# Spring : Autowired object conflicted between users

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-mvc

I am creating a backend application using spring boot, whose users authenticate using a JWT.

when I validate the user's jwt (using a filter), I parse its content into an object that I named "authentication", containing the user's id, name, role...

after creating this object with user data, I autowire it, so that I use it to any class (service, controller...)

Most of the time I have no problem with it. but sometimes I find that this object contains another user's information.

I thought that each user has access to an object containing his information, and if this object does not contain information then he will have an empty object, and not an object of the other users

Can this reasoning create a conflict? and how to solve it?

This is my filter class

```
@Component
class AuthenticationFilter : Filter, Ordered
{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtUtils : JwtUtils
    
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var beanFactory : AutowireCapableBeanFactory
    
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var authentication : Authentication
    
    
    
    override fun doFilter(request : ServletRequest, response : ServletResponse, chain : FilterChain)
    {
        if (request is HttpServletRequest)
        {
            val authFromHeader : Authentication? = getAuthenticatedUser(request)
            
            if (authFromHeader != null)
            {
                authentication.id = authFromHeader.id
                authentication.name = authFromHeader.name
                authentication.role = authFromHeader.role
                authentication.level = authFromHeader.level
                
                beanFactory.autowireBean(authentication)
            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
    
    
    private fun getAuthenticatedUser(request : HttpServletRequest) : Authentication?
    {
        return try
        {
            val jwtToken : String? = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
            
            jwtUtils.getAuthentication(jwtToken)!!
        }
        catch (exception : Exception)
        {
            null
        }
    }
    
    
    override fun getOrder() : Int
    {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
    }
}
```

Comment: `authentication` is shared state in a singleton... Don't share state as that is dangerous.

Comment: thank you @M.Deinum for your reply. but how to have access to the information of each authenticated user? I needed to do this because I have a lot of endpoints, and I thought this is a solution to get user info without extra work on each request

Comment: Well ditch your custom solution and use a proven solution like Spring Security, Apache Shiro which all have that already tackled (and more).

Answer (score 0):

authFromHeader have to be declared in lateinit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).